# Calculating nearby users within a radius with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation, mongoose-schema

I currently have a database of users stored in MongoDB as follows:

```
users: {
  user_id: {
    location: {
      lat: latitude,
      lng: longitude
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to query the users so that when a user inputs a distance parameter he or she receives back other users who fall within a radius of that distance. It seems as if MongoDB's geospatial query operators would be useful, but my location data is not currently stored in geojson format. Would there be another way to determine which other users fell within the radius?

Comment: You also need to create a geolocation index for that mongodb property. Follow the documentation

Comment: I understand, but the problem I'm facing is that I'm not storing my latitude and longitude as geojson data, so even if I were to create geolocation index I wouldn't be able to run any geolocation queries on my data.

Comment: If you're not going to use the geolocation features of the database, then you will have to build your own. How many users are we talking? Can you fit all the user location data in memory easily? Otherwise, you'll have to invent some queries that find users that are near your latitude and near your longitude (you will have to decide what "near" means for your application based on the parameter the user specified) and then once you have a smaller set of users that can fit in memory, you can calculate the actual distances of all of them from your source point and decide which meet your criteria.